# I can't interpolate camera ,what is the problem?

Tags: roblox

```
local cam = workspace.CurrentCamera
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local FocusPart = game.Workspace.Gun
local EndPart = game.Workspace.part12
local part = script.Parent

cam.CameraType = "Scriptable"

cam:Interpolate(EndPart.CFrame, FocusPart.CFrame, 1)
```

Again,I tried fixing the problem by changing some lines but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs for [Camera:Interpolate](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Camera/Interpolate), and there's this note :

> Interpolate can only be used if the current Camera.CameraType is ’Scriptable’, regardless of whether the default camera scripts are being used. If it is used with any other Camera.CameraType an error will be thrown.

So to fix your issue, you need to use the CameraType enum, not a string.

```
cam.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Scriptable
```

Comment: The docs also mention that Camera:Interpolate is deprecated, and you should use TweenService instead.

Comment: Well I used the TweenService but the camera doesnt go and focus where I want

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your script into StarterCharacterScripts.